# How to connect button click function for move slide with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, indexing, slide

I am trying to create a button click function to slide left and right using jQuery.

```
<a href="#" class="goingright point"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="goingleft point"></a>
                        <div class="pfarea">
                            <p class="guide">CLICK TO FOLLOW LINK<span>&#33;</span></p>
                            <ul class="pf_item">
                                <li class="pf1">
                                    <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                                        <div class="pf_preview">
                                            <img src="" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="pf2 on">
                                    <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                                        <div class="pf_preview">
                                            <img src="" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                                        <div class="pf_preview">
                                            <img src="" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                                        <div class="pf_preview">
                                            <img src="" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                                        <div class="pf_preview">
                                            <img src="" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

if I click button class="goingleft", the slide should moves to left side. and if i click button class="goingright", they move to right side. i build the function like this, but this is not working at all... can someone help me?

```
var currentIdx = 0;
var slideLength = $('.pf_item > li').length;


function goingleft() {
  if (currentIdx !== (slideLength - 1)) {
    currentIdx += 1;
  } else {
    currentIdx = 0;
  }
}
function goingright()  {
  if ((slideLength - 1) !== currentIdx) {
    currentIdx -= 1;
  } else {
    currentIdx = (slideLength - 1);
  }
}
$('.goingleft').click(function(){
  goingleft();
});
$('.goingright').click(function(){
  goingright();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way but misses some class modifications in your code to make different slides visible or not.

First - define some styles in your `<head>` section:

```
<style>
li {
    display:none;
}
.on {
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

This tells the browser to hide all `<li>`-elements by default, except the one that has the class `on`. By removing/adding the `on`-class for each list item you will be able to hide/show each slide.

In your HTML-part I have written text where you had image-tags. You can simply use images instead. I also added the texts LEFT and RIGHT for your "buttons":

```
<a href="#" class="goingleft point">LEFT</a>
<a href="#" class="goingright point">RIGHT</a>
<div class="pfarea">
    <p class="guide">CLICK TO FOLLOW LINK<span>&#33;</span></p>
    <ul class="pf_item">
        <li class="on">
            <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                <div class="pf_preview">
                    SLIDE 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                <div class="pf_preview">
                    SLIDE 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                <div class="pf_preview">
                    SLIDE 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                <div class="pf_preview">
                    SLIDE 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="pf_item_wrap">
                <div class="pf_preview">
                    SLIDE 5
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, finally you need to use your code to react on button-clicks. When the user clicks on a button the index is increased/decreased followed by moving the `on`-class to the correct slide and thus making it visible:

```
<script>
    var currentIdx = 2;
    var slideLength = $('.pf_item > li').length;

    function goingleft() {
        if (currentIdx > 1) {
            currentIdx--;
        } 
    }
    function goingright()  {
        if (currentIdx < (slideLength)) {
            currentIdx++;
        }
    }

    $('.goingleft').click(function(){
        goingleft();
        li_ref = "li:nth-child("+currentIdx+")";
        $("li").removeClass("on");
        $(li_ref).addClass("on");
    });
    $('.goingright').click(function(){
        goingright();
        li_ref = "li:nth-child("+currentIdx+")";
        $("li").removeClass("on");
        $(li_ref).addClass("on");
    });
</script>
```